# how to check particular latlng is in particular circle radius

Tags: android, proxy, location, google-maps-android-api-2, alert

i'm working on module in which the person such as driver is in moving state and sending his location regularly on time period, its have waypoints and direction on map, i want to know if the driver has entered in particular waypoint area ? i found Proximity-Alert which is giving the alert if the user entered in particular area or not, but i want to know about other user such as driver, so how can i know that driver is near to particular waypoint or not? my code for Proximity-Alert is given below. can i use it to get alert when driver enter to area or i have to use something else?

```
public class ProximityIntentReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
       private static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1000;

       @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
       @Override
       public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
           String key = LocationManager.KEY_PROXIMITY_ENTERING;
           Boolean entering = intent.getBooleanExtra(key, false);
           if (entering) {
                     Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "entering");
              }else {
                     Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "exiting");
              }
              NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

              Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, ProximityAlertActivity.class);
              PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
              Notification notification = createNotification();
              notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, "Proximity Alert!", "You are near your point of interest.", pendingIntent);

              notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
      }

       private Notification createNotification() {
              Notification notification = new Notification();
              notification.icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
              notification.when = System.currentTimeMillis();
              notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
              notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_SHOW_LIGHTS;
              notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
              notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS;
              notification.ledARGB = Color.WHITE;
              notification.ledOnMS = 1500;
              notification.ledOffMS = 1500;
              return notification;
        }
}
```

ProximityAlertActivity.java

```
public class ProximityAlertActivity extends Activity {
    private static final long POINT_RADIUS = 100; // in Meters
    private static final long PROX_ALERT_EXPIRATION = -1; // It will never expire
    private static final String PROX_ALERT_INTENT = "com.androidmyway.demo.ProximityAlert";
    private LocationManager locationManager;
    private EditText latitudeEditText;
    private EditText longitudeEditText;
    private Button addAlertButton;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_proxymity);

            locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

            latitudeEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.point_latitude);
            longitudeEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.point_longitude);
            addAlertButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.add_alert_button);

            addAlertButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                  public void onClick(View v) {
                         addProximityAlert();
                  }
            });

    }

    private void addProximityAlert() {
           double latitude = Double.parseDouble(latitudeEditText.getText().toString());
           double longitude = Double.parseDouble(longitudeEditText.getText().toString());
           Intent intent = new Intent(PROX_ALERT_INTENT);
           PendingIntent proximityIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, 0);
           locationManager.addProximityAlert(
                  latitude, // the latitude of the central point of the alert region
                  longitude, // the longitude of the central point of the alert region
                  POINT_RADIUS, // the radius of the central point of the alert region, in meters
                  PROX_ALERT_EXPIRATION, // time for this proximity alert, in milliseconds, or -1 to indicate no                           expiration
                  proximityIntent // will be used to generate an Intent to fire when entry to or exit from the alert region is detected
           );

           IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(PROX_ALERT_INTENT);
           registerReceiver(new ProximityIntentReceiver(), filter);
           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Alert Added",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: You should calculate the distance between your location and the centre of the circle. If it is less than the radius you are in. Code to calculate the distance can easily be found. There is even a function in the location manager who will do that for you.

Comment: but my problem is i'm getting driver location every 1 minute duration, if driver passed away from that location in 1 minute? so it will give me wrong information

Comment: No. Why? I see no problems. I dont understand yours.

Comment: i mean i send driver location every minute and receive on other side every minute, if driver passed away from particular location before calculating the distance then what?

Comment: Yes indeed. That is possible. Well its up to you to decide how to handle this. What do you want that happens in such a case?

Comment: i must want to check that if driver has passed that location or not?